# User shortcuts setting in SQL Server Management Studio 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

Do you know where in SSMS 2014 can I set up my own shortcuts?
For example: in ORACLE SQL I set up that

```
sf = select * from
```

By this I only wrote in execution window sf and it wrote select * from.

Where and how can I set it in SSMS 2014?

Thank you.

Comment: You can create your own snippet and then insert it with `Ctrl-K Ctrl-X`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492130(v=sql.120).aspx for details

Comment: You also have keyboard shortcuts  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3178.how-to-create-query-shortcuts-in-sql-server-management-studio.aspx

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have shortcuts. You are talking about SSMS which is now a separate free product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have shortcuts. SSMS is a *separate* product, based on the Visual Studio shell.

SSMS is a [separate free product](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) now, which supports all SQL Server versions from 2008 upwards (including SQL Server for Linux). The latest update came out on December 5. Updates are released regularly every month.

It has the same shortcut functionality as Visual Studio. You can change and define new shortcuts from `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`

You can specify snippets in the Code Snippets Manager, `Tools > Code Snippets Manager` whose shortcut is Ctrl+K, Ctrl+B. You can insert a snippet by hitting Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X

There are several tutorials that explain how to use Code Snippets, eg [Add T-SQL Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492130.aspx) from the docs, [Getting started with Code Snippets feature of SQL Server 2012](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2411/getting-started-with-code-snippets-feature-of-sql-server-2012/), the similar [SQL snippets in SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-snippets-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

It is a good idea to install the latest SSMS version. Now that it's a separate product, earlier versions won't get the same updates as the current one